# Why is the image rotated incorrectly using the Matrix.rotateM method in Media3 Transformer?

Tags: android, matrix, rotation, transformer-model

I just want to rotate the image in one plane
I'm trying to mess around with the Media3 Transformer demo https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/transformer/demo-application

```
 private OverlayEffect createOverlayEffectFromBundle(Bundle bundle, boolean[] selectedEffects)
      throws PackageManager.NameNotFoundException {
    ImmutableList.Builder<TextureOverlay> overlaysBuilder = new ImmutableList.Builder<>();
    if (selectedEffects[ConfigurationActivity.OVERLAY_LOGO_AND_TIMER_INDEX]) {
      float[] logoPositioningMatrix = GlUtil.create4x4IdentityMatrix();
      Matrix.translateM(
          logoPositioningMatrix, /* mOffset= */ 0, /* x= */ -0.95f, /* y= */ -0.95f, /* z= */ 1);
// here I rotate 45 degrees around the Z axis
      Matrix.rotateM(
          logoPositioningMatrix,0, 45f,0f, 0f,  1f);
      OverlaySettings logoSettings =
          new OverlaySettings.Builder()
              .setMatrix(logoPositioningMatrix)
              .setAnchor(/* x= */ -1f, /* y= */ -1f)
              .build();
```

fun from https://github.com/androidx/media/blob/release/demos/transformer/src/main/java/androidx/media3/demo/transformer/TransformerActivity.java

[without rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckOXX.jpg)

[after rotation along the Z axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KbPQ.jpg)

[after rotation along the X axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ymfcu.jpg)

[after rotation along the Y axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdO5i.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I just want to rotate the image in one plane